# How to assign sequence number for different task?

Tags: odoo, project-management

I have create module for project which has field prefix when record save prefix generate with sequence **pro-001**

when any task is created under perticular project task sequence will be generate like **pro-001, pro-002, pro-003**

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
        project_id = vals.get('project_id')
        project = self.pool.get('project.project').read(cr, uid, project_id, context=context)
        if project and project['prefix']:
           new_id =  self.pool.get('ir.sequence').next_by_id(cr, uid, 'project.task', project['prefix'], context=context)

        return super(projectTask, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context)
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: sequence is not generate by project, i don't know how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that requirement i would suggest to define a sequence (`sequence_id` see below) for every project. Look into `account.journal` how it's done correctly.

And then you can use it on `project.task` creation like:

```py
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    project_id = vals.get('project_id')
    project = self.pool.get('project.project').browse(
        cr, uid, project_id, context=context)
    if project and project.sequence_id:
        vals['your_sequence_field_on_task'] = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').next_by_id(
            cr, uid, project.sequence_id.id, context=context)

    return super(projectTask, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context)
```